# SSIS Catalog : Failed to compile scripts contained in the package

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, ssis-2017

We had an SSIS Package which we used to Download some Excel files from the SharePoint and Load it to the On-Prem SQL Database. The Package will Fetch the Files from Sharepoint having the value Pending in the Status field, Process the file and update the status as Completed back to the share point.

This used to work perfectly when it was in On-Prem, Recently we migrated the same to Azure and change the deployment method from File system to SSIS Catalog. Now when We try to Deploy the package in the Catalog, we are getting the following error :

```
Error:
1. Failed to compiled scripts contained in the package. Open the package in SSIS Designer and resolve the compilation errors.
2. CS0234 - The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?), ScriptMain.cs, 16, 17
3. CS0234 - The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?), ScriptMain.cs, 17, 22
4. CS0305 - Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments, ScriptMain.cs, 215, 35
5. CS0246 - The type or namespace name 'ClientContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), ScriptMain.cs, 215, 48
6. The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to install sharepoint libraries on the whatever SSIS runtime you are using. Is this in a VM? Then it follows exactly the same setup the last server would have needed - you need to install all required libraries. Or is it in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It's a VM, and we are using Nuget Libraries for SharePoint,

Comment: Your error is telling you a library isn’t installed or can’t be accessed. SSIS doesn’t know anything about nuget.

Comment: I have the Library installed and the build was successful, But getting the error while trying to deploy the same in another machine. So will there be something that needs to be taken care in the Destination machine

Comment: Yes you need to install the libraries on the runtime machine.

Comment: Did the error solved now?

Comment: @LeonYue, No we compared the drivers in both machines and they are same